# React render page after API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, navigation

When I navigate between pages in my React app, a see a bounce at each page (meaning that page is rendered first without any data [e.g. username, date of birth, images], then few milliseconds/seconds later some details appear on the screen as the API request has finished and updated the state.

For example I have the following pages:

```
<div className="home" onClick={() => history.push('/')}></div>
<div className="user" onClick={() => history.push('/user')}></div>
<div className="settings" onClick={() => history.push('/settings')}></div>
```

This results in behavior that when I click 'settings' button I first go to `/settings` route and then components starts rerendering and bouncing while making API requests. In each of these pages I make one or multiple API requests to get data. I make these requests using `useEffect` hook. For example:

```
const Settings = () => {
  const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState(null);
  const [userImages, setUserImages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUserDetails = async () => {
     const response = await getUserSettingsDetails();
     setUserDetails(response.data);
   }
   const getUserImages = async = () => {
     const response = await getUserSettingsImages();
     setUserImages(response.data);
  }
  getUserDetails();
  getUserImages();
  }, []);

  return ( 
     ... 
  );
}
```

What I want to achieve:

I want that when I am for example on 'homepage', and click to go to 'settings', to navigate and render Settings page only after the API requests finished and I can have all details on the screen immediately. I have a nice line loading component that I want to display in header while loading. (Similar to what YouTube has, it displays a red progress bar when navigating). I also use Redux for this project and I think it could be used here but I do not understand how to do this. Could anyone please explain how to achieve such behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an extra state called `isLoading` and set it true when any fetch of data starts. Then, below the await statement, you can set `isLoading` to false.

So, with this, you can use the `isLoading` state in your JSX code, to make a conditional rendering, for example, you can display a Loading Component while the `isLoading` variable has the value of true, then, when the variable is false, display your page as you want.

```
const Settings = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({});
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getAllInformation = async () => {
      // start loading
      setIsLoading(true);
      // make the request here
      const data = await fetch();
      setState({ ...data });
      // already finished here
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
    getAllInformation()
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Loading />
      ) : (
        {
          /* MORE CODE */
        }
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

hi I think you can use Promise.all([])
and a loading state

```
const Settings = () => {
 const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState(null);
 const [userImages, setUserImages] = useState([]);
 const [loading,setLoading] = useState(false)

 const getUsersInfos = async () => {
  try {
   const result = await new Promise.all([
     getUserSettingsDetails(),
     getUserSettingsImages(),
   ])

   const details = result[0]
   const images = result[1]

   //i'm not sure if we need to test
   if(details.data && images.data){
     setUserDetails(details.data);
     setUserImages(images.data);
     setLoading(true)
   }

  } catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
 }
}

useEffect(() => {
  getUsersInfos();
}, []);

return ( 
  <>
   {loading && (
     ...
   )}
  </>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I believe @Daphaz answer is pretty well, I'll go with a better and cleaner approach using **redux-thunk or redux-sagas**. With redux you can only do simple synchronous updates, and here you will be doing asynchronous updates hence you will need a middleware like those I mentioned.

[Redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)
[Redux-sagas](https://redux-saga.js.org/)

There are tons of examples of usings this middlewares to achieve exactly what you are looking for.